# How fast can the human body temperature change?

Tags: human-biology, medicine, temperature, thermodynamics

I'm really curious about how fast can a human body temperature change?
E.g. how fast can the human body temperature change when the human has fever?

I'm not interested in how fast *fever* changes the temperature, more likely how fast the human body is possible to change it?

I found allot information about how much the temperature changes over the day and so on, but now how fast the human body is "capable" to change it in a certain time span.

Comment: This depends on a lot of things. It's pretty slow if you are limiting the change to be entirely internal. If we get help from environmental extremes though, the change can be quite rapid.